# Разработка метода jQuery

Tags: jquery

В плагине TwitterBoostrap bootstrap-button.js есть такая строчка:

```
$.fn.button.Constructor = Button
```

Button это объект типа класса.

Что означает эта строка? Есть в javascript конструктор, но он пишется с маленькой буквы, почему здесь большая? Если это конструктор, то когда он вызывается?

Полностью код плагина тут: http://pastebin.com/cBvajn8w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526115/238336), надеюсь, сами переведете?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что написав
var btn = new $.fn.button.Constructor();
я получу объект Button из плагина?